# what is wrong with my minmax with alpha beta pruning?

Tags: c#, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

when i apply minmax only to my connect4 game it get right results untill depth 7 and when i apply pruning to increase depth it get wrong results , i need a help to kno what is wrong with my logic or implementation?

```
private int score()
    {
        int winner = check_Winner(); // return 1 if player  win or 2 when pc win or 0
        if (winner == 1) return 10;
        else if (winner == 2) return -10;
        else return 0;
    } 
    public int MinMax(int player_num, int depth, int alpha, int beta)
    {
        List<pair> possiple_moves = new List<pair>();
        get_possible_moves( possiple_moves);
        //================================================
        int score_so_far = score();
        if (possiple_moves.Count == 0 || score_so_far != 0 || depth == 10)// terminal case
            return score_so_far;
        //================================================
        if (player_num == 1)// maxmize
        {
            int max_score = int.MinValue, temp = 0;
            foreach (pair move in possiple_moves)
            {
                cells[move.x, move.y].player_num = 1;

                temp = MinMax(2, depth + 1, alpha, beta);
                if (temp > max_score)
                {
                    max_score = temp;
                    pc_move = move;
                }

                cells[move.x, move.y].player_num = 0;
                alpha = Math.Max(alpha, max_score);
                if (beta <= alpha)
                    break;
            }
            return max_score;
        }
        //==========================
        else
        {
            int min_score = int.MaxValue, tmp = 0;
            foreach (pair move in possiple_moves)
            {
                cells[move.x, move.y].player_num = 2;

                tmp = MinMax(1, depth + 1, alpha, beta);
                if (tmp < min_score)
                {
                    min_score = tmp;
                    pc_move = move;
                }

                cells[move.x, move.y].player_num = 0;
                beta = Math.Min(beta, min_score);
                if (beta <= alpha)
                    break;
            }
            return min_score;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start using Debug and see what is the problem.

Comment: i arleady make it but i dont know why without pruning it worked will but with lower depth

Comment: You should specify your problem in details in which line what do you expect, but what happens. With I have wrong results almost nobody will look into your code. You should specify what is the exact problem. Nobody knows what exactly is depth in your scenario and so on. You should probably read How to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask